# Flat view with folder file is located in

Tags: sharepoint

I have a document library and i want to create a flat view to see all the documents with out the folders, but id like to keep the folder the file is in as a column. It doesn't need to be functional.

The user wants to be able to see what folder the file is located under in a flat view.

---

The User wishes to keep the folder structure. We advised them to use a column attribute but they like folders.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a column of meta data instead of placing the files in a folder in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new view or modify an existing view and in the Edit view in the Folders group 
 "Specify whether to navigate through folders to view items, or to view all items at once. "Select "Show all items without folders"

Comment: John, That is exactly what i did. So now i can see the files in flat view with out the folders. But the users would like to see folder the file is in using the flat view. When I created the view to view files with out folders the files show up but then the users have no idea what folder they file is in. I'd like to find a way to show it as a column in the flat view, it doesn't have to be the folder just the folder name. So the column title would be Folder and the rows would contain the name of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet using the client object, the solution should be similar using sharepoint core

```
List DocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(list);
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'>
                                         <Query>
                                            <Where>
                                               <Eq>
                                                  <FieldRef Name=FSObjType />
                                                  <Value Type=Integer>0</Value> 
                                               </Eq> 
                                            </Where>
                                         </Query>
                                     </View>";
ListItemCollection listItems = DocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(listItems);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

the meta-data fields will all be load to find the path use, the server relitive url, split it by the last`/` everything before that will be the path everything after will be the file name

if you cannot get the server-relitive url in the meta-data use
`listItem.File.ServerRelitive` url